# Adding convolution layer in keras giving errors

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset which has two classes and has 400 features. Each feature is a floating point number. I am trying to build a basic CNN in keras but I am facing the following error. I have checked other solutions but those solutions ask to reshape the training data into `(batch_size, steps, input_dim)`. I don't think that is a valid solution here.

My code and error message are posted below.

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(200, input_dim=400, init='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv1D(100,
                     4,
                     padding='valid',
                     activation='relu',
                     strides=1))
    model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
    model.add(Dense(50))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_CNN.py", line 61, in <module>
    model = create_baseline()
  File "train_CNN.py", line 44, in create_baseline
    strides=1))
  File "/users/prateek.n/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", li                                                                                                                ne 469, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/users/prateek.n/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topolog                                                                                                                y.py", line 552, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "/users/prateek.n/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topolog                                                                                                                y.py", line 451, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(K.ndim(x)))

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected ndim=3, found                                                                                                                 ndim=2
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a convolution across those 400 features? And each of those 400 features is a single number? In that case, you should indeed reshape your data as (batch_size, 400, 1) (i.e. 400 "steps" and one feature per step).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `Conv1D` needs 3 dimensional input of shape `(batch_size, timesteps, features)`. The output from a first `Dense` layer has shape `(batch_size, 200)`. If you want to interpret these 200 features as 200 timesteps of one feature you could simply:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200, input_dim=400, init='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Reshape((200, 1))
model.add(Conv1D(100,
                 4,
                 padding='valid',
                 activation='relu',
                 strides=1))
```

If you want to interpret the input as time sequence you could also:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200, input_shape=(400, 1), init='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(100,
                 4,
                 padding='valid',
                 activation='relu',
                 strides=1))
```

and reshape your input data to have a valid shape. In this case your input will be interpreted as 400 timesteps of one feature and a first `Dense` layer will transform your data to shape `(batch_size, 400, 200)` as `Dense` in Keras > 2.0 is applied independently to each element of a time sequence.

Comment: I have accepted the answer. But, can you explain what do you mean by the two interpretations? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what is interpretation of your input data. If you interpret is a sequence of legth `400` - second approach seems to be more reasonable. If you want to apply `Conv1D` to output from a `Dense` layer then first one is more appropriate.